# When is dequeue size call not thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, deque

In general, operations on the standard containers are [not thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042571/is-stdvector-or-boostvector-thread-safe?noredirect=1&lq=1) ([mostly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626405/is-writing-stddeque-at-different-memory-locations-concurrently-thread-safe)). The `size` call on a `std::vector`, for example, [may fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377712/on-macosx-using-g-is-stdvector-size-thread-safe) when reallocations are happening.

Since a `dequeue` [does not reallocate or move the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235372/will-stl-deque-reallocate-my-elements-c) like a standard vector does, are there still conditions when calling `size` on a dequeue can be unsafe? The most likely scenario seems to be when adding/removing elements in a different thread as the `size` call is being made, but since accessing an [integer is mostly safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350994/is-it-safe-to-read-an-integer-variable-thats-being-concurrently-modified-withou), I'm having trouble thinking of how calling `size` from a separate thread would be problematic.

Comment: *I'm having trouble thinking of how calling size from a separate thread would be problematic.* UB causes all sorts of issues.  Best to just avoid it.

Comment: What (re)allocation (or its absence) has to tread safety? Containers are not synchronized in any way, ergo they are not thread safe. Only case where you can use STL container as thread safe is when it is not muted at all just read. For example when coding in functional style.

Comment: @MarekR one of the users in the comments of the SO links suggested the case where you're computing end() - begin(), but mid computation one of those changes so you get a negative unsigned int. This particular case doesn't seem to be possible for deque, since the memory isn't guaranteed to be contiguous. Does that make sense?

Comment: Unless `dequeue::size()` is guaranteed to be thread safe, implementations are free to do any thread unsafe behavior to calculate the value. The function could iterate through all elements and return the count. It could read a member variable `size`, sleep for 20 seconds, and read `size` again then return the average.

Comment: @NathanOliver agreed. I'm just wondering if there is *really* a case where the size call will be problematic, since the behavior seems *slightly* different than std vector where the question was already answered. If the answer is "can't think of an exact case but it's still not a good idea" I'm fine with that

Comment: Even if `size()` just reads a variable you can have a data race if another thread causes an update at the same time. Data races are always undefined behavior.

Comment: @en_Knight Maybe yous should read about memory ordering before stating such things. [Take a look on that cool lecture](https://scs.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Viewer.aspx?id=e152f2c8-dc26-4dec-84da-eb6eef4984dd).

Comment: Accessing an unsynchronized `int` across threads is **not** safe. The link you provided does not say it's "mostly safe".

Comment: The gcc implementation of `deque` seems to use a similar process as you described in `vector`. `return this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start;` https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_deque.h

Comment: Is your question really, "is it thread safe to read a `size_t`"?

Comment: @John thanks, if you put that in an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @... a few people :) I'm getting a general answer: (1) I'm too optimistic (/naive/misunderstood/whatever) about how nice a read operation is, (2) the behavior from the other answer about vectors applies here anyways. If this is correct, and someone puts it in an answer, I'd be happy to accept it!

Comment: @MarekR thank you for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ever**. Because it's not required to be so in any standard.

The GCC implementation here https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_deque.h is the result of a subtraction:

```
      // [23.2.1.2] capacity
      /**  Returns the number of elements in the %deque.  */
      size_type
      size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start; }
```

Even if size were stored in a `size_t`, or even an `uint8_t`, and `size()` were an inline function to return this variable, C++ makes no guarantees about the atomicity of different ints. Never assume something is threadsafe unless it is guaranteed to be so.

Answer (score 0):

For example like this

```
std::deque<int> dq;
dq.push_back(1);

// thread0
void printElementIfExist() {
    if (dq.size() > 0) {
        std::cout << dq[0] << std::endl;
    }
}
// thread1
void removeElementFromDeque() {
    if (dq.size() > 0) {
        dq.pop_back();
    }
}
```

race condition could allow to access `dq[0]` which is already deallocated.

Back to the `size()` call itself. There are architectures where the read operation is not an atomic operation.

Comment: here I believe it's the access that causes the problem, not the size check, correct? All my accesses, in this scenario, are guarded by locks